# What's a keyboard shortcut for Gmail to show the unread messages with a specific label?

Tags: gmail, keyboard-shortcuts, gmail-labels

I want a keyboard shortcut to take me to the list of unread e-mails with a specific label.

I can type <kbd>g</kbd> + <kbd>l</kbd> then type the label name and `is:^u`, but I want to know if it can be done with a shorter combination.

Comment: Where did the "`is:^u`" search string come from? Specifically, what do the "`^`" and the "`u`" mean? I've only seen [one reference](https://support.google.com/vault/answer/2474474?hl=en) to the "`^`"; they use with "`label:^deleted`" (which doesn't return any results for me, by the way).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know that it is not exactly the answer you are looking for but, did you ever consider using **Labs** feature **Quick Links**. I know that it is not a keyboard shortcut, but with one click, you could achieve what you want to do.

When you have this Labs enabled, simply search `label:your-label is:^u` in the normal search field and then, on the sidebar region of the Quick Links, Click Add Quick Link and name this search.

After, it will be a matter of one click to do this search.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's pretty much all I want, but it doesn't seem to work after I enable the Lab. Nothing changes in the UI. Can it be that the new GMail UI breaks things?

Comment: I have the new UI, and I see it.  It is on the left side, bellow the tags.  Maybe you need to choose Gadgets instead of chat ?